Add Synapse Administrator role assgiment for manged identitiy - 403 authorization error
I am implementing logic that assigns roles in Azure Synapse Workspace. I have the following setup:
Marketplace app that deploys resources to customer subscriptions (it has denied assignments):

creates Azure Synapse Workspace
creates managed Identity
assigns managed identity Owner role in Azure Synapse Workspace
creates container app that will be hosting C# code that will update
role assignments in synapse workspace
adds managed identity to all resources so they can communicate with
each other

After the marketplace app is installed I push the image of my C# app to the ACR and mount it in the Azure Container App.
The app has endpoint that calls service which updates role assignments in Azure Synapse Workspace. It has following steps

Call endpoint on Azure Container App which will trigger service logic
Set managed identity as an identity for assigning roles
Call HttpClient or RoleAssgimentClient (Yeah both are failing) to
assign the roles

I am getting 403 error every time even Managed Identity is set as the owner of the Synapse Workspace and should be able to assign roles like Synapse Administrator
P.S I tried to use https://management.azure.com/.default and https://dev.azuresynapse.net/ scopes
HTTP Client Code
public TokenCredential GetCredential(string tenantId = default)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tenantId) is false)
    {
        return new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
        {
            TenantId = tenantId,
        });
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(EnvironmentVariables.ManagedIdentityClientId))
    {
        return new DefaultAzureCredential();
    }
    var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(
        new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
        {
            ManagedIdentityClientId = EnvironmentVariables.ManagedIdentityClientId,
            TenantId = EnvironmentVariables.TenantId,
        });
    return credential;
}

private async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var credential = credentialProvider.GetCredential();
    var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(
        scopes: new[] { "https://management.azure.com/.default" }
    );
    var tokenRequest = await credential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext, cancellationToken);
    logger.LogInformation(tokenRequest.Token);
    return tokenRequest.Token;
}

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
string roleId = "6e4bf58a-b8e1-4cc3-bbf9-d73143322b78"; //Azure Synapse Administrator
var requestBody = new
{
    roleId,
    principalId = EnvironmentVariables.ManagedIdentityObjectPrincipalId,
    scope = $"workspaces/{EnvironmentVariables.SynapseWorkspaceName}",
    principalType = "ServicePrincipal"
};
var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
var jsonBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestBody);
var content = new StringContent(jsonBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var url = $"https://{EnvironmentVariables.SynapseWorkspaceName}.dev.azuresynapse.net/roleAssignments/{guid}?api-version=2020-12-01";
var response = await httpClient.PutAsync(url, content, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Role assignment created successfully.");
}

RoleAssignmentsClient code
public TokenCredential GetCredential(string tenantId = default)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tenantId) is false)
    {
        return new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
        {
            TenantId = tenantId,
        });
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(EnvironmentVariables.ManagedIdentityClientId))
    {
        return new DefaultAzureCredential();
    }
    var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(
        new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
        {
            ManagedIdentityClientId = EnvironmentVariables.ManagedIdentityClientId,
            TenantId = EnvironmentVariables.TenantId,
        });
    return credential;
}

Guid principalId = new Guid(EnvironmentVariables.ManagedIdentityObjectPrincipalId);
Guid roleId = new Guid("6e4bf58a-b8e1-4cc3-bbf9-d73143322b78"); // Synapse Administrator
string endpointUrl = $"https://{EnvironmentVariables.SynapseWorkspaceName}.dev.azuresynapse.net";
var credential = credentialProvider.GetCredential();
var accessControlClient = new RoleAssignmentsClient(new Uri(endpointUrl), credential);
string roleAssignmentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
string scope = $"workspaces/{EnvironmentVariables.SynapseWorkspaceName}";
var response = await accessControlClient.CreateRoleAssignmentAsync(
    roleId: roleId,
    principalId: principalId,
    scope: scope,
    roleAssignmentId: roleAssignmentId, 
    cancellationToken: cancellationToken);


Are you using system-assigned managed identity of web app to connect synapse workspace?


assigns managed identity Owner role in Azure Synapse Workspace

Even though your managed identity has Owner role in Azure Synapse Workspace, To assign Synapse Administrator role your Managed Identity needs the owner role on resource group and resource it will take time to reflect changes.  That may be the reason to below error:

I am getting 403 error every time even Managed Identity is set as the owner of the Synapse Workspace and should be able to assign roles like Synapse Administrator

Follow the MS document to add Role to your managed identity. You can use Azure portal to add Synapse administrator role to the Managed Identity as follows:
Launch Synapse studio, login to it, go to Manage select Access control click on Add as shown below:

Select Synapse Administrator role and Managed Identity click on Apply as shown below:

The role will add successfully. For more information you can refer to this.

I just found out that error 403 was caused by default deny assignments on all permissions on the managed application. After updating technical configuration and adding Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/administrators/write to bypass deny default deny assignments, app is not getting 403 error anymore :)
